# adding to UICollectionViewCell contentView via nib

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Is there a way to add subviews of a UICollectionViewCell to a contentView via xib? Because I think this is the right way to do so right? I think when I drag and drop UI via xib then it is dropped into the view instead of the contentView

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you drag and drop any Views into UICollectionViewCell XIB, you're dragging to cell.contentView, not cell.view.

Please check in didSelect, you will see all subviews

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *views = [cell.contentView subviews];
    NSLog(@"Select %@",views);
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, `[cell.contentView subviews]` returns an empty array. My xib file is a derived type of UICollectionViewCell and my controls in the xib file are added to the main cell.

Comment: Hi.Every subViews in your Cell display OK after viewDidAppear?@MarkIngram

Comment: still not understand, this is your problem or comment? Can we discuss more at:http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad @MarkIngram

Comment: This is wrong, drag any views into UICollectionViewCell on xib will be added into cell itself direclty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similar to what you are doing to populate the TableViewCell via nib.

- Create a nib
- Add the subviews into it with proper unique tags
- Register Collectionview with the cell you created

  UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ECVCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ECVCell"];
- Use `viewWithTag:` method to get the instance of added view inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`
  method